# Safari not accept cookies from my backend api - Spring

Tags: java, spring, cookies, https, safari

I'm building a simple shop in spring, but I'm experiencing an issue with the Safari browser. It doesn't seem to store my cookies.
Everything works fine on other browsers.
Both frontend and backend are on different domains and of course work on HTTPS.

Frontend: https://graimpreza.pl/

Here's a snippet of code on how I generate the cookies

```
public Cookie generateCookie(String name, String value, HttpServletResponse response){
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(name,value);
    cookie.setPath("/");
    cookie.setMaxAge(360000);
    cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
    cookie.setSecure(true);

    response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", String.format("%s=%s; Max-Age=%d; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None", name, value, 360000));
    return cookie;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/blog/goodbye-third-party-cookies/. You are using 3rd party cookies, this will soon be disabled in all browsers. Likely it's already the case in Safari.

Comment: Thank you. I moved my backend to the same domain and set the samesite attribute to lax, and it's working fine.